# In-app updates returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE even though Google Play shows that one is

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-play-services, in-app-update

I read all the similar posts to this problem and tried the suggested solutions, but I'm still coming up empty. I'm wondering if the problem is in Android Studio (I'm running the current latest version, 3.6.1) because it gives me a build error on AppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo():

[image]

[image]

So to get the app to build, I had to make this change to the code:

```
        com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
```

Has anyone had a similar problem with Studio 3.6.1? I've been struggling with this problem for several days and have ruled out the obvious stuff. The app uses Firebase and I'm building with the latest Play Services library (17.1.0), but I doubt that's related to this.

Comment: It's just an import issue, you already imported `Task` which is from `com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task` but you need `com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task`. So remove `import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task` than it will be fine.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq Thanks for your suggestion. I had to make several changes in my code to accommodate, but now we'll see if it helped.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq No change. I still am not seeing updates to my app.